# Помогите исправить слоган

Tags: грамотная-речь, редактура, реклама

Как переделать слоган, чтобы он звучал правильно?
**Найди авиабилет по той цене, которую хочешь!**

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать в безличной форме.

**Здесь можно найти авиабилет по желаемой цене.**

Еще варианты:

"Авиабилеты по желаемым ценам",

"Авиабилеты по адекватным ценам".

Answer (score 0):

1) **Авиабилеты. Назови свою цену — и купи билет по этой цене!**

2) **У нас вы купите билет по вашей цене!**

Comment: 1. Обращение на ты Вас не смущает? 2. "Назови" в контексте интернет-поиска?

Comment: Обычная практика для слогана, например:Переходи на лучшее. Ты в норме, пока ты в форме. Живи на яркой стороне. А обращение на вы здесь не подойдет по структуре: не укладывается в размер.  Основной принцип слогана: коротко и стильно.

Comment: *Назови свою цену — и купи билет по этой цене!* Это не рекламный слоган, а русская народная сказка какая-то. "Принеси то, не знаю что".

Comment: "У нас вы купите билет по вашей цене!". Мне понравилось.   Удар прямо в подсознание! И уверенность, что купите! И на вы лучше чем на ты.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант: "**Авиабилет по любой цене**". Но кто поверит такой рекламе?

Comment: Просили переделать слоган, я его переделал (улучшил) . Чем не ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы знаете, бессмысленно переделывать, что изначально не несет смысла.

Но е рекламы свои законы, там подобный абсурд (а как еще назвать?!) встречается как вполне оправданный прием. Вот так например.

**Авиабилеты по вашим ценам.**

И докажите мне, что здесь изменен смысл. Хотя, сами понимаете, что так не бывает. Но ведь так же и в исходном варианте.

Примеры в других ответах мне не нравятся - либо стилистически далеки от рекламы, либо (у М_Г) подмена понятия.

Comment: Небольшая модификация: **Авиабилеты по названным вами ценам.**

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите, чтобы слоган действительно работал, могу посоветовать такой вариант:
**Цену на авиабилеты устанавливаете вы!**

Почему именно так? Ответ будет уже не столько из области русского языка, сколько из области психологии. Существует байка, что в свое время автор слогана "Новое поколение выбирает Pepsi" чуть ли не озолотился. До этого слоган переводили дословно: "Pepsi - выбор нового поколения", но он не работал. Потом один умный человек изменил порядок слов в соответствии с психологическими особенностями восприятия фраз русскоговорящими потребителями. В результате, новый слоган буквально "взорвал" рекламный мир, и теперь такой порядок слов в слоганах стал одним из "золотых стандартов".